# Running into an import error between markup and jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, package

I'm working on using the `Mageck-VISPR CRISPR-CAS9` workflow for data analysis. In practice, I have run into this error using `VISPR` when I use the following command.

```
(mageck-vispr) Charlies-MacBook-Pro-2:~ charlie$ vispr server/Users/charlie/Downloads/esc-testdata/results/esc-mle.vispr.yaml
```

What the terminal spits out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charlien/miniconda3/envs/mageck-vispr/bin/vispr", line 6, in <module>
    from vispr.cli import main
  File "/Users/charlie/miniconda3/envs/mageck-vispr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/cli.py", line 28, in <module>
    from vispr.server import app
  File "/Users/charlie/miniconda3/envs/mageck-vispr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/server.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/Users/charlie/miniconda3/envs/mageck-vispr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

In an attempt to fix this I did a PIP uninstall of both markup and `jinja2` and did a PIP install and update of both packages afterwards.